# Minimum set of files needed to recover a MySQL table (MyISAM and InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, recovery, disaster-recovery

When recovering a MyISAM table the only file that is strictly needed is the data file (`tablename.MYD`) - the rest of the files (the index file `tablename.MYI` and `tablename.frm`) can be recreated from the data file using `REPAIR TABLE`.

Assume I'm using InnoDB (with the "`innodb_file_per_table`" setting) instead - what is the minimum set of files needed to recover a database table from file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the data file and the log files then InnoDB will be able to recover. See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.0/en/innodb-recovery.html) (and containing chapter) on MySQL.com for more. InnoDB recover is quite different to MyISAM in that is more "built-in" as it were.

Answer (score 0):

To recover MyISAM table you need frm and MYD file. myisamchk can rebuild the index (MYI file)

For InnoDB - depends on innodb_file_per_table. If it's OFF (default), your data in ibdata1. But you need .frm file too. 
If it's ON - you need ibdata1, the respective .ibd and .frm file.